# inspect the parameters to "use", and pass on the rest?

Tags: perl, module, oop

I have a Perl module and I'd like to be able to pick out the parameters that my my module's user passed in the "use" call.  Whichever ones I don't recognize I'd like to pass on.  I tried to do this by overriding the "import" method but I'm not having much luck.

**EDIT:**

To clarify, as it is, I can use my module like this:

```
use MyModule qw/foo bar/;
```

which will import the **foo** and **bar** methods of **MyModule**.  But I want to be able to say:

```
use MyModule qw/foo doSpecialStuff bar/;
```

and look for **doSpecialStuff** to check if I need to do some special stuff at the beginning of the program, then pass qw/foo bar/ to the Exporter's **import**

Comment: Pass on to what? Exporter? Can you post some code indicating what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, you would do this to gain [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html)'s import() functionality (this isn't the only way, but it's a common method that works):

```
package MyClass;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter 'import';  # gives you Exporter's import() method directly
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(stuff more_stuff even_more_stuff);
```

...and then you will get an `import()` method automatically created for you. However, if you want to do something extra in `import()` before the normal method gets a hold of the parameters, then don't import Exporter's `import()`, and define your own, which calls Exporter's `import()` after making any alterations to the argument list that you need:

```
package MyClass;
use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'Exporter';

sub import
{
    my ($class, @symbols) = @_;

    # do something with @symbols, as appropriate for your application
    # ...code here left as an exercise for the reader :)

    # now call Exporter's import, and import to the right level
    local $Exporter::ExportLevel = 1;
    $class->SUPER::import(@symbols);
}
```

However, I'm wondering why you need to do this... the standard behaviour of dying when being passed an unrecognized symbol is normally a good thing. Why would you want to ignore unrecognized symbols?  (**Edit:** I see now, you want to specify additional behaviour on top of importing symbols, which is not uncommon in Perl. So defining your own import() method is definitely the way to go here, to grab those values.)

---

<sub><sup>PS. if you only want to import symbols which are defined by @EXPORT_OK, it could be implemented like this:</sup></sub>

```
@symbols = grep {
    my $sym = $_;
    grep { $_ eq $sym } @EXPORT_OK
} @symbols;
```

Comment: OK cool!  Now what would the best way to pick out the symbols I recognize and leave the rest?  Grep does not seem to fit the bill.

Comment: Unrecognized symbols don't get ignored, they just get passed on to `Exporter`, where they will kill the script if they remain unrecognized.

Comment: I don't want to ignore unrecognized symbols... I want to process them and then remove them

Comment: import is 100% based on `caller`, so you can't just use SUPER::import unless you want everything to get exported to the wrong package. That's why export_to_level is there.

Comment: At first I had the same problem, but after doing $Exporter::ExportLevel = 1 it's working for me.

Comment: Set $Exporter::ExportLevel = 1 before calling SUPER::import and then the symbols will get exported to the package that's calling your module (and then set it back to 0 in case any other modules want to use Exporter).

Comment: What about local $Exporter::ExportLevel = 1; ?

Comment: code updated, nice catch @hobbs, I clearly didn't test quite thoroughly enough :)

Comment: I would change the comment in your answer to read... "process @symbols and remove from @symbols everything we have processed".  The point is that my "import" is looking for a certain special list of parameters to act on (not symbols to import) and anything that is not on that special list should be passed on to the superclass's import

Answer (score 3):

The typical use of `Exporter` is to declare your module to inherit from `Exporter`, and to have `Exporter`'s `import` method called implicitly when your module is used. But this keeps you from creating your own `import` method for your module.

The workaround is to use Exporter's [`export_to_level`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Exporter#Exporting_without_using_Exporter's_import_method) method, which performs `Exporter`'s functions without explicitly going through the `Exporter::import` method. Here's a typical way to use it:

```
package My::Module;
use base 'Exporter';   # or use Exporter; our @ISA=qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(...);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(...);
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (...);

sub import {
    my ($class,@import_args) = @_;
    my @import_args_to_pass_on = ();
    foreach my $arg (@import_args) {
       if (... want to process this arg here ...) {
          ...
       } else {
          push @import_args_to_pass_on, $arg;
       }
    }
    My::Module->export_to_level(1, "My::Module", @import_args_to_pass_on, @EXPORT);
    #or:  $class->export_to_level(1, $class, @import_args_to_pass_on, @EXPORT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... any reason to prefer this solution to the simpler one by "ehter" above?

Comment: @Joel: I think in this case they are equivalent. Exporter's docs say "[use] 'export_to_level' ... in situations where you can't directly call Exporter's import method" which doesn't seem to be the case  here, but it definitely works just as well as the other way.. it's just longer. :)

Comment: @Joel, I'm trying Ether's code, but I can't get it to work. Maybe I'm not doing something right, but the methods I mean to export don't show up in the main symbol table.

Comment: OK, got it to work, but had to include the line `$Exporter::ExportLevel=1` before calling `$class->SUPER::import(...)`

Comment: I think calling SUPER::import is better than export_to_level because that way I get all the functionality of handling @EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK, etc., right?

Answer (score 2):

I have done it this way in my modules:

```
sub import {
    return if not @_;
    require Exporter;
    my $pkg = shift;

    # process @_ however you want

    unshift @_, $pkg;
    goto &Exporter::import;
}
```

you can also inherit from Exporter if you want unimport and the like.

Comment: clever -- steps into `Exporter::import` but doesn't push a new frame onto the stack (so return values from `caller` are unaffected). You can't put any code after the `goto` statement and before the end of the method, though (you know, if you wanted to do that).

Comment: Perl's goto is tricky, but it can really be handy sometimes! (if you know what you're doing) :)